# Executar comando SQL em uma máquina virtual

Tags: php, c#, sql

Eu tenho um form, que possui os campos de login e senha.

Eu quero fazer um comando de update em sql em uma máquina virtual ao qual claro, quem executar o programa não vai ter privilégios pra executar comandos na máquina virtual.

Eu quero atualizar assim por exemplo (eu sei que o comando não está certo, é só um exemplo simplificado):

```
UPDATE 'launcher' = 0 WHERE 'account' = textbox.Text and 'login' = textbox2.Text
```

---

Então, como eu posso fazer isso? Eu sei que a melhor forma para fazer essa consulta é pelo um php dentro da máquina virtual que quero acessar o banco de dados apenas para dar um update. Até mesmo pela segurança.

Resumindo: Eu quero enviar o login e a senha para o programa PHP e ele deve executar a query com os dois dados.

Eu sei o código em php e a estrutura em C#, mas não sei como fazer essa ligação para o php passando as variáveis.

Comment: Se você quer mandar um comando para um servidor, não necessariamente você precisa saber que o servidor executa PHP, certo? como é a interface de recebimento dos dados dessa aplicação PHP? Web Service? REST API?

Comment: Sou tão perguntante como você, mas o comentário do Cigano Morrison Mendez é pertinente. Eu não me preocuparia com o código em onde ele seria executado não. Eu me preocuparia em passar valores, parâmetros e aí sim, em cada ambiente seu, executar conforme a sintaxe de cada ambiente. Faria um serviço para disponibilizar esses novos valores e ao consumi-lo, aí sim, eu chamaria a sql correta.